# WCF client cannot connect to WCF service hosted in IIS via ServiceHost?

Tags: wcf, iis, client, servicehost, wsdualhttpbinding

I have this scheme:

IIS

- hosts: OperatorService.svc (connects to **ClientService**)
- Global.asax (on start): hosts **ClientService** via ServiceHost

WPF client

- connects to **ClientService**

If I go to **OperatorService** the service is activated, web application started, and **ClientService** is successfully hosted at `http://localhost:8020/ClientService`. So far so good.

I can now access the **ClientService** in the aforementioned URL in a browser, I can add it through *Add Service Reference*. It's simply there - running.

But when I try to connect via generated client (looks OK), it suddenly doesn't work. Throwing:

`There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8020/ClientService that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.`

Moreover the **OperatorService** connects to this **ClientService** itself (it is a WsDualHttpBinding to provide notifications). It subscribes itself correctly to this service (calling a method) and it works (same URL as my WPF client).

**Why can't I connect from my WPF client?**

WPF client config (only relevant sections):

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8020/ClientService" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="DefaultBindingClientService" contract="Server.IClientService"
        name="DefaultBindingClientService">
        <identity>
            <servicePrincipalName value="host/OHS-UPC" />
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
</client>
<bindings>
    <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultBindingClientService" />
    </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

IIS hosted web.config (for **ClientService**)

```
<service name="TelPro.OHS.Server.Services.ClientService" behaviorConfiguration="UnsecuredBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBindingClientService" contract="TelPro.OHS.Server.Services.IClientService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
        <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8020/ClientService"/>
        </baseAddresses>
    </host>
</service>

<wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DefaultBindingClientService"/>
</wsDualHttpBinding>

<behavior name="UnsecuredBehavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
</behavior>
```

IIS hosted web.config (for OperatorService -> ClientService)

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8020/ClientService" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="DefaultBindingClientService" contract="ClientNotificationServer.IClientService" 
        name="DefaultBindingClientService" />
</client>

<wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DefaultBindingClientService" />
</wsDualHttpBinding>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, OperatorService is also a client of ClientService. Can you show the relevant part of OperatorService's web.config (client endpoint and bindings) in order to compare it to the WPF client?

Comment: I've added the configuration for OperatorService as a client to ClientService. That was the first place I checked as well, because one is connecting and the other is not. So now I think they're identical, it seem like it is an issue of rights. I can create ClientServiceClient from WPF client to a service (Endpoint/Binding seems correct), but when I call a method it fails. Therefore I'm puzzled.

Comment: I can connect to a service from WcfTestClient as well (so it's there), unfortunatelly WcfTestClient doesn't allow calling the methods because it doesn't support WsDualHttpBinding. So I can't verify the last step.

Comment: Just guessing now. What about the servicePrincipalName in the WPF client config, is it correct? I don't know what kind of error would show on an incorrect SPN, so could you change the SPN to something definitely **INcorrect** and see if it's the same "no endpoint listening" error?

Comment: Oh, and check the config that WCF Test Client generates! It's available in the tree view.

Comment: I've tried it without SPN before and still the same thing (WcfTestClient contains basically the same config as I do, it also includes the SPN). This is weird like everyone has right to that service except me. I also added netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8020/ClientService user=Everyone and give rights on a web application to Everyone. I'll try deliberately invalid SPN as you've said.

Comment: Wrong SPN did the same thing. Able to connect to service (i.e. create client instance), but unable to call a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by switching to port 80.

```
http://localhost/ClientService
```

Somehow that works. I've tried to add rules to port 8020 everywhere (even stopped firewall), checked any port forwarding, Azure endpoints, etc. My theory is that the problem when server is trying to connect back (callback) to client and has no rights or something. My guess would be that IIS hosted service doesn't have enough rights to connect back. If anyone can still shed some light on the why, I would gladly switch answer to them. But so far I'm just glad it works regardless the port.